# jQuery .get not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

I have the following code that I run whenever the `.information` element is clicked. I am trying to add the `aboutMe.html` document to the `#text` element when the `.information` is clicked:

```
$(".information").click( function() {
    $.get("aboutMe.html"), function(data){
        $("#text").html(data);
}});
```

For some reason the document is not added to the page when `.information` is clicked.

Comment: You have an extra parenthesis in your example after the `"aboutMe.html"`

Comment: Check the console for errors?

Comment: Basic troubleshooting ...  does your panel show any 404s?  Have you added alerts to see if the listener is firing? Etc

Comment: The console doesnt show any errors

Comment: Interestingly, his mistake doesn't result in a syntax error. The comma turns from being an argument separator to the comma operator.

Comment: When I replace the html(data) with eg. html("sometext") it does show up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your parentheses and braces are wrong. It should be:

```
$(".information").click( function() {
    $.get("aboutMe.html", function(data){
        $("#text").html(data);
    });
});
```

Your callback function was outside the argument list of `$.get()`.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work for ýou

```
$(function() {

$('.information').click(function(){


$('#text').load("aboutMe.html");

});

});
```